# What Windows OS to install on 15-g201nx HP Notebook?

Tags: windows, installation

What compatible **Windows** Operating System version (XP, Vista, 7, 8, or 10) & (32 or 64-bit) could I install on an HP [15-g201nx](http://support.hp.com/ca-en/document/c04608440) Notebook to run smoothly and stably?

Comment: They're all compatible, but with the low amount of RAM and relatively slow CPU, XP would probably run best. It is out of support now though and I doubt many places sell legitimate product keys. There are evaluations you can try of Windows 10 without a product key also, to see if you're happy with the performance before purchasing a legitimate key.

Comment: @Jonno Another question to come, [How to get 32-bit drivers for 15-g201nx HP Notebook?](http://superuser.com/questions/1023972/how-to-get-32-bit-drivers-for-15-g201nx-hp-notebook)

Comment: Upgrade the memory to 4gb and you can install W7 or 8 64bit, and HP has all the drivers..http://support.hp.com/ca-en/drivers/selfservice/HP-15-g200-Notebook-PC-series/7486438/model/7804849

Comment: @Moab Unfortunately, I won't planning to upgrade the memory to 4gb. I still need to install the 32-bit version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 32-bit is the more conservative choice because your computer only has 2GB RAM, and Windows laptops that ship with Windows 8 or Windows 10 usually come with Windows 32-bit preinstalled. This is because 64-bit programs use about 50% more memory then their 32-bit counterparts. If you have a choice of operating systems, you will get the longest period of support if you install Windows 10 because it is the latest version of Windows. Don't install an unsupported version of Windows if you want the operating system to run smoothly and stably. Windows Vista Extended Support will end on April 11, 2017. If you exclude Windows Vista, that leaves you with a choice of Windows 7, Windows 8 or Windows 10. Windows 8 and Windows 10 have a little bit less memory usage than Windows 7.

Comment: The listed operating system on the documentation is FreeDOS. How could I find that an OS is supported or not?
Moreover, [How to get 32-bit drivers?](http://superuser.com/questions/1023972/how-to-get-32-bit-drivers-for-15-g201nx-hp-notebook)

Comment: Usually computers that ship with FreeDOS have no operating system preinstalled. When you install your own operating system, you would normally overwrite FreeDOS with your operating system of choice because you don't need FreeDOS anymore. So all you need to do to find out if an operating system is supported is to Google search for the OS's "minimum system requirements". If you want to save money on the operating system and get faster performance Ubuntu MATE 15.10 32-bit would be a good choice, and most of the drivers are built-in in Ubuntu MATE, so you don't need to search for missing drivers.