# How to get 32-bit drivers for 15-g201nx HP Notebook?

Tags: windows, laptop, drivers, 32-bit

I'm trying to find 32-bit drivers for 15-g201nx HP Notebook. I'm finding only 64-bit installation files on the official [Software and Driver](http://support.hp.com/ca-en/drivers/selfservice/HP-15-Notebook-PC-series/7486438/model/7804849) Downloads page.
Where could I download the official 32-bit drivers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of those installers have 32bit drivers included, just try to install them, if they don't it will just fail to install.

If you download a SP.xxxxx file you can unzip it using 7-zip or other tool, this will show you all the drivers included and for what OS, as an example I downloaded your realtek lan driver SP69625 and uncompressed it, here is what it shows.

But you dont need to do this to install, just execute the SPxxxx file and it will install the proper driver and bit version for your system.

**Unpacked**
[image]

**If you go inside the WIN7 folder for example you can find 32 and 64 bit folders**
[image]